# Tracking Node Orientation

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, nodes

I'm currently working on an app and I have my Node rotating by angle every time I touch by using the TouchesBegan method. Now I've been trying to  figure out if theres a way to tell what way a node is orientated?

For example if you have a square is there a way to give every side a diffrent value (1,2,3,4)? Can you tell what value is faceing down?

I was thinking if I could tell what angle the node has been rotated by
( one touch = 90 degrees / two touches = 180 degrees....)
 I could use that value for features ill be needing in the future. However I don't know if that value is ever saved, or how to go about saving it
 Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the angle your `SKSpriteNode` is facing use the `zRotation` property on you `SKSpriteNode`. Bear in mind this is measured in radians, if you specifically need it in degrees you can convert from radians to degrees with the following code:

```
let degrees = sprite.zRotation * 180 / CGFloat(M_PI)
```

Alternatively, if all you wanted to do was know how many times the user had touched the screen - you could use a variable that you increment every time `touchesBegan` in called.

Hope that helps!